# How to test axios both success and failure case?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, axios, react-testing-library

I have a React application. I am using React-testing-library for testing. I am trying to write test cases to cover my axios failure case but not able to.

To test, I have created a folder called `src/__mocks__` and which contains a file called 'axios.js'. The content inside is -

```
export default {
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: "success" }))
};
```

In my component.test.js test file, I am able to test the success scenario of the axios call. But not sure how to test the failure case. Content is -

```
it("Test axios call", () => {
    axiosMock.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
    data: { greeting: "hello there" }
    });
});
```

Note - The axios call inside my component is under

```
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('url')
    .then((res)=>{console.log(res)})
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
},[])
```

And also note, that I am able to test the failure case by changing the Promise.resolve to Promise.reject inside the axios mock. But, at any point in time, I am able to test either, not both!

Comment: I use a pattern that is different from the one that you're using in your example but that I think is easier to manage. You can find all the details [here](https://www.polvara.me/posts/how-to-test-asynchronous-methods/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution written in TypeScript.

To convert it to JavaScript, replace `(axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>)` with `axios` and change any references to `ts` to `js`.

`index.ts`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

function main() {
  return axios
    .get('url')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

export { main };
```

Unit test:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { main } from './';

describe('main', () => {
  it('success', async () => {
    const spyOn = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    (axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>).get.mockResolvedValueOnce('success data');
    await main();
    expect(spyOn).toBeCalledWith('success data');
    spyOn.mockRestore();
  });

  it('error', async () => {
    const spyOn = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    (axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>).get.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('some error'));
    await main();
    expect(spyOn).toBeCalledWith(new Error('some error'));
    spyOn.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

`__mocks__/axios.ts`:

```js
const axiosMocked = {
  get: jest.fn()
};
export default axiosMocked;
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57835066/index.spec.ts
  main
    ✓ success (12ms)
    ✓ error (4ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    success data

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    Error: some error
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/57835066/index.spec.ts:15:68)
        at step (/Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/57835066/index.spec.ts:32:23)
        at Object.next (/Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/57835066/index.spec.ts:13:53)
        at /Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/57835066/index.spec.ts:7:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (/Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/57835066/index.spec.ts:3:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/57835066/index.spec.ts:13:15)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:102:37)
        at resolve (/Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.066s
```

You can find the completed TypeScript demo [here](https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57835066).

Answer (score -1):

From a testing point of view, you should test the effect of the failed request, some error message popup etc.
With the spy you are strict connect with implementation, not effect but in some cases that make sense, its your choice :)